# Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992], locale en-US)

Tags: flutter, windows, dart

Click And sow screenshort (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRVd3.png)

```
!Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at C:\flutter.
Consider adding C:\flutter\bin to the front of your path.
```

Solve my flutter problem

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggest you need to add `C:\flutter\bin` to the PATH in your enviroment variables:

Go to your advanced system settings (or search for environment variables):

[image]

Double click on `Path` and add the suggested directory: `C:\flutter\bin`

[image]

Apply > Ok